# Java IMS Connect API: HWS0008E Error

Tags: java, ims-tm

I need to connect to IMS Connect through Java, using the IMS Connect API.

I've set up a Websphere with the TM Resource Adapter and deployed the IVP Project. It works like a charm.

Because we want to avoid Licensing for Websphere and Rational (which seems to be necessary if you want make proper Use of the Resource Adapter), I also tried out the plain Java IMS Connect API.

I followed the instructions  [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9NWR_3.1.0/com.ibm.ims.iconapij31.doc/ies1_iconapi_issuingcommands.htm), and set up the Project and the Code.

The initial connection to the Host is working, but executing a command fails with an HWS0008E error code (see also: [HWS0008E](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9NWR_3.1.0/com.ibm.ims.iconapij31.doc/ims_hws0008e.htm)).

The reason for the error is an EOFException, the full stack trace being:

```
12.03.2015 11:36:36 com.ibm.ims.connect.impl.ConnectionImpl receive
SEVERE:     IOException caught in Connection.receive().  Exception caught was: com.ibm.ims.connect.ImsConnectCommunicationException: HWS0008E: Failed to send or receive messages to and from IMS Connect hostName [host], portNumber [port]. Original error: [EOFException]
com.ibm.ims.connect.ImsConnectCommunicationException: HWS0008E: Failed to send or receive messages to and from IMS Connect hostName [host], portNumber [port]. Original error: [EOFException]
    at com.ibm.ims.connect.impl.ConnectionImpl.receive(ConnectionImpl.java:1609)
    at com.ibm.ims.connect.impl.TmInteractionImpl.execute(TmInteractionImpl.java:660)
    at Main.main(Main.java:66)
```

What I have noticed is that in the settings for the Connection Factory I can set Username and Password, while the Connection asks for a "RACF" User.

My suspicion is that the Connect API does not support the type of Authentication (just plain host User and password) that we're using, but the Resource Adapter does.

Does anybody have any experience in this matter and can help me out with any tips or advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to invoke an IMS Transaction avoiding any license issues or cost. There are multiple ways to do that, both TMRA and SOAP Gateway are dependent (unless you want to hand generate the content which you can) on tooling from RAD that will require a license.

TMRA can be used as a standalone API, similar to how IMS Connect API operates and then there is also the Mobile feature that allows you enable your transactions as REST services that only requires the IMS License you must already have; these are your no cost options. I recommend you look into the mobile feature pack, it includes the runtime and the eclipse tooling.

As far as your IMS Connect HWS00008E error, its because the IMS Connect must be enabled with RACF=Y and the IMS Connect API is sending the default RACF credentials: 

RACF ID = "RACFUID "

RACF Password = "RACFPSWD"

RACF Group = "RACFGRUP"

So, contact your IMS Admin and ask them for valid RACF credentials then set them either pragmatically or in the TmInteration properties file correctly, or if in fact RACF is not enabled for this IMS Connect (RACF=N) then try setting the credentials to 8 blanks like so:
 
 public final static String BLANK_USERID = "             ";
 
 setRacfUserId(BLANK_USERID);
 
 setRacfPassword(BLANK_USERID);
  
setRacfGroupName("");

There are better places to get an answer for this, I just happened to stumble across this. Contact me if you have more questions or want me to put you in touch with those owning these products.

Try the listserv monitored by IBM IMS employees: http://imslistserv.bmc.com/scripts/wa-BMC.exe?INDEX